# Fatal error while upgrading

Tags: 7, upgrading

While upgrading to Drupal 7.39 from 6.37, after copying the new files over into the site's directory, when I tried to navigate to the website I see a blank page with the following error: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare template_preprocess_block() (previously declared in /home2/mccotter/public_html/test/includes/theme.inc:2042) in /home2/mccotter/public_html/test/modules/block/block.module on line 1038`

I have not yet run update.php, and when I try to the page appears blank.  I was unable to sign in as the maintenance user, but I set `$update_free_access = TRUE`.

For reference, the site that I am attempting to upgrade is jailtraining.org/test

Comment: try `cache clear` or `registry rebuild` option. I hope you have backup of the site and disabled all the `contributed modules` that should be your first step :) first upgrade the core and after that upgrade other modules.

Comment: Yeah, everything's backed up and I've disabled all the contributed modules.  I'm pretty new to Drupal, though, so could you point me somewhere that explains how to use the cache clear or registry rebuild options?

Comment: clearing the cache didn't help, I still have yet to try the registry rebuild option, though

Answer (score 1):

Pre-First back up your site.

First upgrade to the most recent version of Drupal 6. The follow instructions here to move to Drupal 7:

https://www.drupal.org/documentation/upgrade

Have trouble? Explain where you are in the process at that point so one might help.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!  I have been following the upgrade instructions outlined in Upgrade.txt included with the Drupal 7 download, and the latest version of Drupal 6 is 6.37.  I'm sorry if wasn't clear enough with where I am in the upgrade process, but I'm at the point where you would normally run update.php.